# mutating admission webhook static namespaceselector

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

Does anyone know if there is a way to define static selectors based on the namespace name instead of label selectors? The reason is that some of the namespaces are created by an operator and I don't have any control over the labels.

Thanks
Essey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems no, never heard, never found anything like that.

As per  [MutatingWebhookConfiguration docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/rest_api/extension_apis/mutatingwebhookconfiguration-admissionregistration-k8s-io-v1.html) property `namespaceSelector` has a type [LabelSelector [meta/v1]](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/rest_api/objects/index.html#labelselector-meta-v1) that supports

```
.matchExpressions
matchExpressions is a list of label selector requirements. The requirements are ANDed.
```

and

```
.matchLabels
matchLabels is a map of {key,value} pairs. A single {key,value} in the matchLabels map is equivalent to an element of matchExpressions, whose key field is "key", the operator is "In", and the values array contains only "value". The requirements are ANDed.
```

And in the end everything is dependent on [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels).

For sure you saw [these examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels)

Answer (score 1):

Each namespace has the so-called [well-known label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#kubernetes-io-metadata-name) `kubernetes.io/metadata.name`

So your `namespaceSelector` can be something like:

```yaml
namespaceSelector:
  matchExpressions:
    - key: kubernetes.io/metadata.name
      operator: "In"
      values:
        - "staging"
        - "demo"
```